# Using python 3.2.2 tkinter I create a canvas with scrollbars attached but the data inside the canvas doesn't scroll when I move the scrollbars

Tags: canvas, python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar

Using python 3.2.2 tkinter I create a canvas with scrollbars attached but the data inside the canvas doesn't scroll when I move the scrollbars. Syntax issue or bug with tkinter?

example code:

```
from tkinter import *

## GUI color map ###
black = "#000000"

root = Tk()
root.minsize(100,100)
root.maxsize(500,500)
root.resizable(0,0)

topFrame = Frame(root, bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)
topFrame.pack()

xscrollbar = Scrollbar(topFrame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
xscrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

yscrollbar = Scrollbar(topFrame, orient=VERTICAL)
yscrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

conFrame = Canvas(topFrame, bd=0, scrollregion=(0, 0, 1000, 1000),
                xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set,
                yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)

conFrame.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
xscrollbar.config(command=conFrame.xview)
yscrollbar.config(command=conFrame.yview)

for i in range(1,30):
    function_name = 'my'+str(i)+'ItemList = StringVar()'
    exec(function_name)
    function_name = 'my'+str(i)+'Item = '+str(i)
    exec(function_name)
    function_name = 'my'+str(i)+'ItemList.set(my'+str(i)+'Item)'
    exec(function_name)
    function_name = 'my'+str(i)+'ItemListEntry = Entry(conFrame, width=148,     foreground=black, textvariable=my'+str(i)+'ItemList)'
    exec(function_name)
    function_name = 'my'+str(i)+'ItemListEntry.pack(side=TOP, padx=2)'
    exec(function_name)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

The scrollbars *do* scroll the canvas. The widgets you are creating (in a *highly* unusual fashion) are not part of the canvas, so they don't scroll. If you use the drawing commands on the canvas you'll see that the canvas items do in fact scroll.

In order for the widgets to scroll, you must embed them in the canvas with `create_window`. If you're trying to create a scrolling frame, the typical solution is to put all your widgets in a frame, use `create_window` to add that frame to the canvas, then set the `scrollregion` to the size of the frame (which you have to do after a screen update since the size isn't calculated until the widget is actually rendered)

On a side note, why are you using exec? It makes your code extremely hard to understand, and you get no benefit in return. Are you aware you can replace those 10 lines with something considerably more simple? For example:

```
var = {}
for i in range(1,30):
    var[i] = StringVar()
    var[i].set(i)
    e = Entry(conFrame, width=148, foreground=black, textvariable=var[i])
    e.pack(side=TOP, padx=2)
```

Comment: thanks a ton for the help. I was definitely missing the create_window. I have implemented you iteration code along with create window and I now have a working scroll frame.

Answer (score 1):

Working code example:

```
from tkinter import *

## GUI color map ###
black = "#000000"

root = Tk()
root.title("Canvas Scrollbar Example")
root.minsize(100,100)
root.maxsize(500,500)
root.resizable(0,0)

topFrame = Frame(root, bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)
topFrame.pack()

xscrollbar = Scrollbar(topFrame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
xscrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

yscrollbar = Scrollbar(topFrame, orient=VERTICAL)
yscrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

canvasFrame = Canvas(topFrame, width=500, height=500, scrollregion=(0, 0, 1000, 1000),
                xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set,
                yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)

canvasFrame.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

xscrollbar.config(command=canvasFrame.xview)
yscrollbar.config(command=canvasFrame.yview)

entryFrame = Frame(canvasFrame, bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)
entryFrame.pack()

var = {}
for i in range(1,30):
    var[i] = StringVar()
    var[i].set(i)
    e = Entry(entryFrame, width=148, foreground=black, textvariable=var[i])
    e.pack(side=TOP, padx=2)

canvasFrame.create_window(0, 0, window=entryFrame, anchor='nw')

mainloop()
```